# Laravel 9 : wrong roles (spatie/laravel-permission)

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-9, laravel-permission

I use Laravel 9, breeze and the package spatie/laravel-permission and I made some modifications to be able to assign a role after the authentification:
(I check the number in the column "id_role" from my table User to known the role )

AuthenticatedSessionController:

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate();

        $request->session()->regenerate();
        $user = Auth::user();

        if ($user->id_role==2) {
            $user->assignRole('admin');
         }
        if($user->id_role==1)
         {
            $user->assignRole('user');
         }
         //test
        return redirect('/');
        //return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
```

And I used the following seeder to created those role:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Reset cached roles and permissions
        app()[PermissionRegistrar::class]->forgetCachedPermissions();

        // create permissions
        Permission::create(['name' => 'edit comments']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'delete comments']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'create comments']);

        Permission::create(['name' => 'edit projects']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'delete projects']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'create projects']);

        Permission::create(['name' => 'delete images']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'create images']);

        // create roles and assign existing permissions
        $role1 = Role::create(['name' => 'user']);
        $role1->givePermissionTo('edit comments');
        $role1->givePermissionTo('delete comments');
        $role1->givePermissionTo('create comments');

        $role2 = Role::create(['name' => 'Super-Admin']);

        
    }

class Database2Seeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $role1 = Role::create(['name' => 'admin']);
        $role1->givePermissionTo('edit comments');
        $role1->givePermissionTo('delete comments');
        $role1->givePermissionTo('create comments');
    }
}
```

But the problem is than every time I'm login as a 'admin' I have the role 'admin' and 'user' .

Like in this blade (view) in see the content for the both role in the same time:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
        <tr>
            <td>"{{ $comment->com }}"</td>
            <br>

            @role('user')
                USER
            @endrole

            @role('admin')
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('comments.destroy',$comment->id)  }}">Delete</a>
            @endrole
```

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
        <tr>
            <td>"{{ $comment->com }}"</td>
            <br>

            @role('user')
                USER
            @endrole

            @role('admin')
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('comments.destroy',$comment->id)  }}">Delete</a>
            @endrole
```

Comment: Your `DatabaseSeeder` doesn't define a role called `admin` at all.

Comment: Scroll down it's in the class "Database2Seeder" (inside the same block of code)

Comment: check `@hasrole('admin')/@hasrole('user')` and comment the result

Comment: done but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you assigned both roles to the user.

Check `models_has_roles` tables and remove the extra assigned role.

Comment: I have already run them both using a commande 
"php artisan db:seed --class=DatabaseSeeder" and "php artisan db:seed --class=Database2Seeder"
Should it not be enough ?

Comment: Yeah its enough

Comment: can you provide more information

Comment: check non-directives like @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('user'))

Comment: and also comment results for table models_has_roles

Comment: same issues with "@if(Auth::user()->hasRole('user'))"

Comment: and the table models_has_roles seems to be fill and working correctly 
What informations could I provide to help solve this issue ?

Comment: The logic says that the user has both user and admin roles... check if the authenticated user has not both roles in the models_has_roles

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253098/discussion-between-mahdi-rashidi-and-varius).